# How to await gathered group of tasks?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have that code

```
import asyncio
   
async def f():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('done')
    
async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(f())
    asyncio.create_task(f())
    pending = asyncio.all_tasks()
    group = asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
    await group

asyncio.run(main())
```

I don't know why it is working forever. I would like to end program when all tasks from group done their job.

Python 3.9

Edit: Ok... I have it. `all_tasks` gives me not only tasks that are created by me. Is there any equivalent for `all_tasks` but without "main task"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`main` is also coroutine, awaiting `main` inside `main` will never end.

```
{
    <Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<f() running at /tmp/t.py:3>>,
    <Task pending name='Task-1' coro=<main() running at /tmp/t.py:11> cb=[_run_until_complete_cb() at /home/falsetru/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py:184]>,
    <Task pending name='Task-3' coro=<f() running at /tmp/t.py:3>>
}
```

Instead, explicitly specifying tasks that call `f()` will not block

```py
async def main():
    pending = []
    pending.append(f())  # OR  pending.append(asyncio.create_task(f()))
    pending.append(f())
    group = asyncio.gather(*pending, return_exceptions=True)
    await group
```

Comment: So is there any good reason to use "all_tasks" method insinde run?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz, You can call all_takss, but awaiting all of them will cause block because of trying to call coroutine to wait itself which will never end. Is there reason not to explicitly list what to await?

Comment: It's not answer for my question. I know that I can call "all_tasks" (I did it). I asked if there is any good reason for that.

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz, I don't get your question. I thought I answer the reason part.

Comment: I noted that I should explicitly list what to await. I'll do it. I will tell to do it to my future children. It is good answer. Now there is second one and it is very simple: is there any good reason for calling "all_tasks"?

Comment: You told me that I should explicitly list what to await. Ok. So what for is "all_tasks"? Could you give me any situation/reason for that?

Comment: @PiotrWasilewicz, It's used in `asyncio.run` to clean up remaining tasks. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5f87915d4af724f375b00dde2b948468d3e4ca97/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L56 NOTE: it's called in normal function, not in coroutine. I don't know another use case.

Comment: that was what I asked :)